# Ionic Slidebox Content Scrolling

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the ionic slidebox and loading a html template in a slide that's getting list data.  The issue is it won't scroll all the way to the bottom.  The bottom half is cut off, as shown in the picture.

Any ideas?[image: list in ionic]

Comment: [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/scroll-content-inside-slide-box-fixed-updated/35429) may be help..!

Comment: You can try to change the marbin-bottom of the list